# SAS: Split input file over many output datasets using macro variables

Tags: macros, sas

I've struggled with this for some time and am not sure if this is entirely possible (perhaps the macro can't resolve properly within the data step..?)

I'm using a data step to input several text files into one SAS data set. At the same time, i'd like to split them back out again based on a *different* parameter in the data.

Ideally, I'd like to use a macro variable in the output library name but the macro variable won't resolve:

> WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference LVEL not resolved.

And the same data are output to all the files (as if the output &Test statement isn't there).

The data look like:

```
TIME    LEVEL   LAT LON HGT
1586616 1000    90  5   229
```

And the code:

```
%let lower_bound = 1979;
%let upper_bound = 1981;

%MACRO FILELOOP ;
    %DO J = &lower_bound %TO &upper_bound ;

   data library.file_1000
        library.file_2000
        library.file_3000
        ;
    infile ".../hgt&J..txt" delimiter='09'x firstobs=2 obs=5; 
    input time level lat lon hgt;

    // I want to use the level variable to determine the output SAS file;
    call symputx ("lvel", level); 

    %let Test = library_&lvel.;
    output &Test;
    run;

   %END ;
  %MEND ;
%FILELOOP ;
```

Comment: Remember that macro code is evaluated first. Thus, at the time `%let Test = library_&lvel.;` is evaluated, the data step code that creates the macro variable has not been run.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. So there's no easy way to resolve this? Using a select statement makes the code really slow...

Comment: lithic, you need to use if then else logic (or case) in your output. `if level=1000 then output library.file_1000;`